# Make expressions equal to 6 using exactly four 4s

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

- You must use all four 4s.
- You may use addition (+).
- You may use subtraction (-).
- You may use multiplication, such as with asterisks (*) and/or grouping symbols.
- You may not use any division.
- You may not use decimal points.
- You may not use any concatenation.
- You may use grouping symbols, such as parentheses and/or brackets.
- You may not use any type of factorial signs.
- You may use up to four square root symbols, including the use of nested square roots.
- You may not use exponentiation.
- You may not use logarithms.
- You may not use trigonometric functions.
- You may not use any other numbers, characters, or operations, to include no other roots.
- This is in base 10.

Try to create and post 10 additional --> essentially <-- different solutions.

Permutations are the same.

This was moved to this site, because it is a math puzzle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think these are all essentially different and within the rules

> 1. $\sqrt{4} + 4 + 4 - 4 = 6$
>  2. $\sqrt{4} + 4 + \sqrt{4} - \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  3. $\sqrt{\sqrt{4\times 4}} + \sqrt{4 \times 4} = 6$
>  4. $\sqrt{\sqrt{4\times 4}} +\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  5. $(\sqrt{4} \times 4) - 4 + \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  6. $\sqrt{4 \times 4 \times 4} - \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  7. $\sqrt{4 \times 4} + 4 - \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  8. $((4-\sqrt{4}) \times 4) - \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  9. $\sqrt{\sqrt{4 \times 4} \times 4} + \sqrt{4} = 6$
>  10. $\sqrt{4+4-4} + 4 = 6$

Comment: I may post some additional solutions tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

These are some additional solutions:

11. $ \ \sqrt{\sqrt{4\sqrt{4*4 \ } \ } \ }  \ + \  4 =  \ 6$
12. $  \ 4\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{\sqrt{4*4 \ } \ } = \ 6$
13. $ \ 4 + 4 - \sqrt{\sqrt{4*4 \ } \ } = \ 6$
14. $ \ \sqrt{(4 + \sqrt{4})(4 + \sqrt{4}) \ } = \ 6$
15. $ \ \sqrt{ \sqrt{4 \ }(4*4 + \sqrt{4 \ }) \ } = \ 6$
16. $ \ \sqrt{4*4\sqrt{4} + 4 \ } = \ 6$
17. $ \ 4 + \sqrt{\sqrt{4 \ }(4 - \sqrt{4 \ }) \ } = \ 6$